# Two non-homeomorphic spaces with continuous bijective functions in both directions

Tags: general-topology

I was asked the following question: if two topological spaces $X, Y$ are such that there exist a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ continuos and bijective and a function $g:Y\rightarrow X$ continuous and bijective, then are the two spaces homeomorphic?

I would say that the answer is No, but I didn't find any counterexample so far.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30661/non-homeomorphic-spaces-that-have-continuous-bijections-between-them